# Wordpress Pods: Index in Template

Tags: wordpress, templates, podscms

Is it possible to get a pod items index in the template? For instance, if I have a pods variable that has ten entries in it, could I make a template that renders each entry with its place in the list or, even better yet, if it's first/last as such:

`Rendering item {@index} out of {@total} called {@title}`

Note: I mean the index in the scope of the group of items being rendered. Not the posts ID or something else. If this doesn't exist it would be a great feature to have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with PHP:

```
Total in this list: <?php echo $obj->total(); ?>
```

Or you can get the total (across all pages, if using pagination or limiting):

```
Total Found: <?php echo $obj->total_found(); ?>
```

Or you can get the current position in the loop (new in Pods 2.3):

```
Current Position: <?php echo $obj->position(); ?>
```

Or you can even do an nth check (CSS nerds know what I'm talking about in regards to how nth-child works):

```
<?php
    if ( $obj->nth( 'even' ) )
        echo 'even row';

    if ( $obj->nth( 'odd' ) )
        echo 'odd row';

    if ( $obj->nth( '1n+3' ) )
        echo 'you get the picture';

    if ( $obj->nth( '3n+0' ) )
        echo 'you get the picture';
?>
```

For info about nth, it just takes the same input as nth-child does in CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

If you'd like these available as magic tags, please submit a feature request at http://pods.io/submit/

Comment: Great! But can I get the index of the current pod from within a template as above? For instance, I'd like every third item to have a specific class when rendered in the template using a `{@index} % 3` statement.

Comment: Edited my answer to add that

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go but I hope that should do it!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! I'm tempted to leave this kind of stuff in a page template but making into a pod template in the CMS makes it easier to update and use across a site. Any suggestions on best process?

Comment: Might be nice to have the short cuts for these, at least for index and total.

Comment: I recommend coding in the theme page templates instead of Pod templates, it's easier to keep under version control.

Comment: What do you mean by shortcuts?

Comment: Sorry I meant the magic tags by "shortcuts." I did notice that the `$obj->position` only works in the latest beta build. Just a heads up for everyone out there. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement. My scenario is that I need to detect first element so that I can display it in a slideshow. Inside template, I declare a global variable:

```
 <?php global $counter; 
    if ($counter == 0) {
        $class='active'; 
        $counter++;
    } else {
        $class='';
    }?>
```

Then I echo variable $class to where i want.
By this way, I cannot know totally how many row but It sold my problem.

Comment: Seems a bit dangerous. You can use the `$obj` properties as outlined by Scott above. They're fully supported in the latest Pods versions. One less global variable is always a good thing in my book.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is deprecated in Pods templates. Now you should use Pods Frontier plugin or put PHP code in WP templates.